# Ubuntu on Mac installation

Tags: partitioning, mac

I would like to install Ubuntu 64 bit on Intel Mac with Yosemite. I would like to continue using both OS X and all the applications and Ubuntu.
Since the latest version of Ubuntu allows double installation without partition, can I choose this option without loosing anything previously installed on my Mac?

Comment: You do have to partition, but it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can use both OS harmoniously.
All you need to do is freeing up some space to install Ubuntu.
You can do it either by using Disk Utility on OS X and shrink your working partition.
On El Captian it look like this.
[image]

Or, you can let Live Ubuntu media to do it while installation by adjusting the slider (red circled), here it's showing Windows 7 but the procedure for OS X is exactly the same.
[image]

Then install Ubuntu alongside OS X and by default GRUB will be installed. Select Ubuntu to use Ubuntu or OS X to use OS X.

If GRUB is not installed you still can boot into Ubuntu by pressing down your option key on the Macbook while booting.